# why it show undefined before array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i am using angular js to read json.

but it would show undefined if I use "+=".

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

var ojt= JSON.parse(text);

var moduleA = angular.module("ModuleA", []);
moduleA.controller("MsgController", function ($scope) {
    'use strict';
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $scope.Message += ojt.employees[i].firstName;
    }
    });
```

the result like this:

```
    undefinedJohnAnnaPeter
```

what's wrong?

Comment: Can you update with what you are expecting as output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Message` is undefined, and then you `+=` some strings onto it, therefore resulting in your problem. Assign `$scope.Message`to an empty string beforehand to get rid of the error.

```
$scope.Message = ""
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $scope.Message += ojt.employees[i].firstName;
}
```

Edit: If you want to add new lines after each name add `\n` in between the names.

```
$scope.Message = ""
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    $scope.Message += ojt.employees[i].firstName + "\n";
}
```

Comment: No problem, don't forget to upvote and accept, if your question is answered

Comment: i tried it before, but it doesn't work... it just add a space between names

Comment: Where are you outputting it? `\n` works almost everywhere. What do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to put John in row 1, Anna in row 2, and Peter in row 3

Comment: But where would you like to output it? console.log()? alert()? A REST endpoint? Inside the dom?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized `$scope.Message`, so on the first iteration you are using the `+=` operator on an `undefined` property. Just initialize it to an empty string before the loop:

```
    $scope.Message = '';
    for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        $scope.Message += ojt.employees[i].firstName;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the variable $scope.Message is undefined

try this:

```
    var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
    '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
    '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

    var ojt= JSON.parse(text);

    var moduleA = angular.module("ModuleA", []);
    moduleA.controller("MsgController", function ($scope) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.Message ='';
        for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
        $scope.Message += ojt.employees[i].firstName;
        }
        });
```

Comment: This can't work because at the point you're assigning the empty string, $scope isn't in scope (ironically).

Comment: thx all, but how can i break them into different line. coz it's useless if i add <br>

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing there is creating a new String. Instead of using this

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
  '{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
  '{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';
```

you should use this

```
var text = {
  "employees": [{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Anna",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  }, {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Jones"
  }]
};
```

This would create a JSON in which you could access object properties through dot notation (object.key).

**EDIT:** Oh wow, I totally didn't see you are parsing your string into a JSON object. Sorry for that. In this case my answer isn't the correct one to satisfy your question.